# Signing Locally

Tags: sdk, docusignapi, local, offline

Is it possible to integrate the DocuSign sdk in such a way so that the signing can be done completely in local environment where there is no internet connection that is without sending the document to DocuSign through API and storing the signed documents to local directly? I don't want to send the documents to be signed to the DocuSign cloud through API. If yes can anyone please share code example or helpful link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign has an appliance - DSA. The appliance can be bought, installed, configured by you. You would have to first do all of that before you can make any API call without internet. 
More information on the appliance and how you can try it out is here - https://developers.docusign.com/dsa-api

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was really helpful. Can you please let me know if it include facilities to sign word, excel too apart from the pdf? Is bulk signing available there?

Comment: yes, it does, it includes a few popular file formats.

Comment: It will be really helpful if you kindly let me know if in the DocuSign cloud one(not the DSA), is it possible for a user to sign his/her own signature even he/she doesn't have a DocuSign account? In the github demo (qs-csharp-master) I found that account id is passed in parameter. So please let me know how it is possible to sign without docusign account. If possible, please share any api link that can be helpful

Comment: yes, it is possible. If you have questions that are not about DSA - please submit new questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have posted a separate question. Kindly help with some specific api examples/demo

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is that DocuSign might be able to see your documents, you can use the DocuSign Security appliance. That way your company has the encryption keys used with your documents.

If you don't want your documents to leave your building, use the DSA as Inbar mentions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was really helpful. Can you please let me know if it include facilities to sign word, excel too apart from the pdf? Is bulk signing available there?

Comment: The cloud DocuSign eSignature service accepts Word, Excel, etc but first creates a PDF version of the original. The DocuSign Signature Appliance can digitally sign Word and Excel files themselves--no PDF involved.

Comment: It will be really helpful if you kindly let me know if in the DocuSign cloud one(not the DSA), is it possible for a user to sign his/her own signature even he/she doesn't have a DocuSign account? In the github demo (qs-csharp-master) I found that account id is passed in parameter. So please let me know how it is possible to sign without docusign account. If possible, please share any api link that can be helpful

Comment: Yes, for DocuSign eSignature signing, the signer does NOT need a DocuSign account. See the developer center, developers.docusign.com for examples. Ask a new question in StackOverflow if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have posted a separate question. Kindly help with some specific api examples/demo